# ExtJS: Date field writes the date one day back?

Tags: date, extjs, model, field, crud

I'm using a `'Ext.form.field.Date'` and on CRUD process it writes given date as one day back. I mean if I select `05 June 2018`, it writes as `04 June 2018`.

I've checked related `model` and `widget` itself but nothing seems weird! Why this could be?

Here is model statement and field;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.FooModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'mydatefld', type: 'date', dateReadFormat: 'c', dateWriteFormat: 'Y-m-d'},

//and implementation
Ext.define('MyApp.BaseDateFld', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Date',
    xtype: 'basedatefld',
    format: 'd.m.Y',
    flex: 1,
    labelAlign: 'right',
    name: 'MyDate Fld',
    fieldLabel: 'MyDate Fld',
    bind: '{currRec.mydatefld}'
});
```

Each time saves date as on XHR request payload;

```
2018-06-05T21:00:00.000Z //But should be 2018-06-06T06:05:00.000Z
```

**Update**:
I've tried change `dateWriteForm` to `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` and `'Y-m-d H:i'` but still noting changes on `payload` and keep decrease one day and sets time to `21:00:00`

As well tried to change compouter TS to some another as *@Alexander* adviced but nothing changed.

**Update 2:**
I've over come the current issue but really a very DRY solution, so not safe!

Below there is `insertion` method *(`update` method is almost same as this)* and formating the related `date` value on here, thusly became success.

Server accepting the `date` format for this field as **Y-m-d**, so I've stated `dateWriteFormat` on `model` and `submitFormat` on `datefield` as **'Y-m-d'** but it keeps write the date value with `timestamp`.

When I check `rec` param on method it is as `2018-06-06T21:00:00.000Z`(The TZ part shouldn't be here!). And `store` param changes the givin `date` one day off as `2018-06-05T21:00:00.000Z`.

Still not sure why I can't convert/format through `model` or `field`.
Thanks for advices.

```
recInsertion: function (rec, store) {
        store.getProxy().url = store.getProxy().api.create;       
        rec.data.givindate = Ext.Date.format(rec.data.mydate, 'Y-m-d'); //This is current solution to format date! Which is really not safe and will cause DRY.         
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: store.proxy.url,
            method: 'POST',
            jsonData: JSON.stringify(rec.data),
            callback: function (options, success, response) {
                Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('showspinner');
                if (success) {
                    Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('refreshList');
                }
                else
                    Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('savefailed');
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Could you change your system time zone to the other half of the globe (UTC+X to UTC-X or vice versa) and check again?

Comment: dear @Alexander you mean with computer's timezone?

Comment: Yes, computer time zone, if you wish to call it that.

Comment: @Alexander I thought already replied to you; but I've missed. Well I've changed timezone but still field write dates on payload as I explained on post:  `2018-06-05T21:00:00.000Z //But should be 2018-06-06T06:05:00.000Z`

Comment: @Alexander you'll notice that keep sets Time as `21:00` and through all changes I made such as; diff `dateWriteFormat`, it keeps state the time as `21:00`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this from the code you provided. Can you try to reproduce [in a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) and share the result?

Comment: @Alexander Can not reproduce same issue on Fiddle, it works correct!! but there is exact same issue on Sencha forms, I'm trying same solution but not works for me @ https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?181344-Date-values-are-always-off-by-one-day&p=1319098

Comment: @Alexander since issue comes on `payload` I think this is not a problem about server-side right? Because it response as how is payload

Comment: I fear no one will be able to reproduce this except you. I cannot help you with that. Please check whether you have any side effects from elsewhere in the application.

Comment: @Alexander this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h4f&view/editor) behaves as exact issue I'm facing; Type '2018-06-07' in *TimeStamp In* field and it response as `2018-06-06T21:00:00Z` on *TimeStamp Out*. When I type with `2018-06-07T21:00:00Z` then response as expected; `2018-06-07T21:00:00Z`

Comment: That fiddle even contains special functions that do just that, `convertFromUTC` (line 189) and `dateToISOString` (line 40).

Comment: So what I get; I've to be able send current time with payload. I've using `submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'` but still load to payload as `T21:00:00:00Z`

Comment: @Alexander what i am missing here exactly? As I mentioned above am I unable to send current time?

Comment: I cannot say, It works in all my tests and as I said, the fiddle you showed me has special code in place to do the conversion.

Comment: @Alexander I've overcome the issue with a non-safe solution. Could you please check out  *'Update 2'* section.